# Why is only a small part of the stream captured when I try to take a picture with the webcam?

Tags: javascript, css, getusermedia

I am trying to take a snapshot of a video feed from a webcam. The preview works fine, but when I try to capture it and turn it into a picture only a very small part of it is captured. A 320x150 part of the right top corner.

Already tried:

- Changing CSS display property
- Setting canvas width and height to
  video height (Which shows 1200x720, so that is correct
- Changing the location of the canvas.

CSS:

```
    canvas 
{
    display: none;
    position:fixed;
    top: 0;
    left:0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
video
{
    height:100%;
    width:100%;

     
    object-fit:cover;
     
}
```

Javascript:

```
var constraints = { 
    video: {width: {exact: 1280}, height: {exact: 720}}
};
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia(constraints).then((stream) => { video.srcObject = stream; });

function take_snapshot(type) 
{
    var v = video.videoWidth;
    var h = video.videoHeight;

    console.log("width =" +v+ "height= "+h );
  //This shows 1200x720
    canvas.style.width = v;
    canvas.style.height = h;
    canvas.getContext('2d').drawImage(video, 0, 0, video.videoWidth, video.videoHeight);
    let image_data_url = canvas.toDataURL('image/jpeg');
    console.log(image_data_url);
    // data url of the image
    var http = new XMLHttpRequest();
    var url = 'save.php';
    var params = 'image='+image_data_url;
    http.open('POST', url, true);

//Send the proper header information along with the request
    http.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded');

    http.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
    if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200) {
        alert(http.responseText);
    }
    }
http.send(params);
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id ="cameraContainer">
<div id="camera">


<video autoplay="true" id="cameraPreview"></video>

<div id="overlay">
<img id="overlayImage" src="">




</div>
</div>
 
<div id="buttonContainer">

<div id="button">
<button id="pictureButton" class="btn btn-success btn-block">Maak Foto</button>
</div>

</div>
</div>
</div>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

The image is the same, when saved or displayed. The data image url is also very short (just 1-20kb). Videoheight and width are correct, so the issue seems to be somewhere in the capture function.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set the size of the actual canvas, like this:

```js
    canvas.width = v;
    canvas.height = h;
    canvas.style.width = v;
    canvas.style.height = h;
```

Just changing the style width/height doesn't make the canvas bigger. When a canvas isn't given an explicit width and height in pixels it gets, [according to the MDN documentation, a default width of 300](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCanvasElement/width) x 150. It's not hard to believe a browser used a default of 320 x 150 instead, though.